# Replacing two old dimmer switches

Tags: switch, dimmer-switch

I'm trying to replace two old dimmers with two new dimmers. These are two separate dimmers, each controlling a different light. I'm having a difficult time figuring out how to wire the new dimmers.

- New dimmer + wirings of old dimmers: https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7krP.jpg

[image]

[image]

[image]

- Fronts of old dimmers: https://i.stack.imgur.com/z3tVY.jpg

[image]

[image]

- Here is a link to the new dimmers I purchased: https://www.leviton.com/en/products/6672-1lw
- Old dimmer #1: Top brown wire is hot
- Old dimmer #2: White wire is hot

I know that the green wires on my new dimmers are ground. But I'm not sure which wires on the old dimmers are ground. I'm not even sure if the old dimmers have ground wires.

I'm also not sure whether the dimmers I purchased are even compatible with these old wirings. I purchased single pole dimmers, but perhaps my old dimmers are not single pole?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Just a note: I've turned off my main circuit breaker and have purchased a non-contact voltage death stick by which I've confirmed that these old dimmers have no power.

Comment: Are the old dimmers controlling the same light? Or are they two separate dimmers, each controlling a different light? If you can find any model #s on the old dimmers, add them to your post.

Comment: Thanks, I added these details to the question. I'm still searching for the model numbers... will add when/if I find them.

Comment: Very common for the old ones not to have explicit grounding wires or grounding screws. So the fact that they have 3 wires suggests that they are "3-way" and there's another switch controlling the same light in each case. Or something's odd, here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me, that looks like a simple resistive dimmer -- two wires for hot and dimmed-hot (both black, interchangable in this design) and one wire for safety ground (green).

The old dimmers may indeed not have ground wires; they may have assumed that they are being installed into a metal (grounded) electrical box.

The fact that the old dimmer has a *white* wire makes me suspect that this box is wired as a switch loop; "neutral is always white but white is not always neutral."

We'd need to see more of how the old dimmers are actually wired to be certain of that; a better photo, with the switch and dimmer pulled further out so we could see the actual connections, would help a lot.

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't scrolled down enough for the back of the second one - fixed. Remove the "m" or use the original links to see full size.